Reeb graph of (x^2-1)^2?
What is the Reeb graph of $(x^2-1)^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$?
Reeb graph is defined as follows :
1- Given a topological space $X$ and a function over it $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$,
2-The level set of $f$ at value $c$ is $f^{-1}(c)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=c\}$,
and then consider the connected components of the level sets of $f$ and define the equivalence relation ~ as follows :
3-Two points
$ 

,

∈
X
$ are equivalent $(

∼
)$ if they belong to the same connected component of a level set of $

$ and the Reeb graph is $X_f=X/\sim$.
My attempt
1- For $c<0$, the level set is empty.
2- For $c=0$, the level set consist of the points $x=\pm1$.
3-For $0<c<1$, the level set consists of four points $x=\pm\sqrt{1\pm\sqrt{c}}$.
4-For $c=1$, the level set is $x=0, x=\pm\sqrt{2}$.
5- For c>1, the level set consist of two points.
All of these points are disconnected. At the end I don't know how to construct the graph from these level sets and I am thankful to anyone who have a hint to do it.
